# How do I echo a variable into a file using python

Tags: python, typeerror, python-3.8

I was writing a script to go with my homemade smart home network and I came upon a problem storing variables in a file. Here is an abridged version of the code

```
import datetime
import os

log = open('log.txt')

def timestamp():
    errortime = ('Timestamp: {:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.datetime.now()))
    print(errortime)
    errortime = str(errortime)

def errormessage():
    //code

def consolelog():
    log.write('Timestamp: ' + timestamp())
    log.write('Error Type: ' + errormessage())
    log.write('------------------')

try:
    prit('hello')
except:
    consolelog()
    print('done')
```

The code is meant to try the code 'prit('hello') which would come back as a syntax error thus storing the variable(errortype) as Syntax Error.  After this I was trying to insert a timestamp and the error type variable into a log.txt file which was returning the following error:

```
log.write('Timestamp: ' + timestamp())
can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

can anyone explain a way to input variables into a file without receiving a TypeError?

Comment: You have to return a value from your function. return errortime

Comment: @SeaverOlson : I don't see how this question is related to bash.

Comment: Typo: `prit` should be `print`

Comment: @Barmar prit is on purpose to trigger Syntax Error

Comment: ``prit`` does not trigger a ``SyntaxError``, it triggers a ``NameError``. None of your functions ``return`` anything. The logic of ``errormessage`` makes little sense, comparing different builtins against each other. Please [edit] your question to detail what you are trying to do. Preferably, remove the unrelated, broken code and create a [mcve] just for the writing task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime
import os

log = open('log.txt', 'w')


def timestamp():
    errortime = (
        'Timestamp: {:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.datetime.now()))
    print(errortime)
    errortime = str(errortime)
    return errortime


def errormessage(e):
    errortype = ''
    if isinstance(e, OSError):
        errortype = ('OSError')
    elif isinstance(e, SyntaxError):
        errortype = ('SyntaxError')
    elif isinstance(e, AssertionError):
        errortype = ('AssertionError')
    elif isinstance(e, NameError):
        errortype = 'NameError'

    return errortype


def consolelog(e):
    log.write('Timestamp: ' + timestamp())
    log.write('Error Type: ' + errormessage(e))
    log.write('------------------')


try:
    prit('hello')
except Exception as e:
    consolelog(e)
    print('done')
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`timestamp()` shouldn't do its own printing, it should just return the string.

You also need to use `datetime.strftime()`, not ordinary string formatting.

```
def timestamp():
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime('Timestamp: {:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}')
```

Comment: this fixed the TypeError but now that line is returning a UnsupportedOperationError Exception has occurred: UnsupportedOperation
not writable

Comment: You need to use `strftime()` to format the time.

Answer (score -1):

First of all when opening a file you should determine the mode you are working with the file:

```
log = open('log.txt', 'w')
```

here 'w' is used to indicate that we want to clear the file if it already exist or create it if it doesn't and then write to it from the beginning. Otherwise if we want to preserve the current file and append new data to the end we should use the 'a' (append) mode.

Another important thing to notice is that you need to close the file after you finish making changes to it so your changes will be saved; Thus after the `log.write()` you need to add `log.close()` .

The error you are getting is because the timestamp function does not return anything (Actually it return NULL). When you use `'Timestamp: ' + timestamp()` what you want is `timestamp()` return the current timestamp. But printing the errortime in the timestamp function doesn't do the trick; You need to return the errortime variable from the function by adding `return errortime` to the bottom of the function.